# Possible solutions to process two images into one

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Hi Im new to computing vision and I am currently stuck at this problem. I have 2shots of component(One is classing RGB and other is IR) and I would like them to overlap with small opacity. Problem is shots are in different dimensions and on slightly different zoom/angle so simlpe resize of smaller one wont put component on correct place. I was able to achieve it using programs like Inkscape but would like to have it automatic since there are more pictures and sets might be from different angle as well.
Here are pictures and something I would like to achieve:
[RGB shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7vZi.png), [IR shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsxK0.png) and [final merged](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w35Wu.png). I would appreciate and possible solutions for this problem, since Im new its hard for me to choose path to take and Im not sure if there is anything programs can do with bad quallity of IR shots. Thanks for possible help.

Comment: If you are using OpenCV search for `cv2.addWeighted()`. You can determine the opacity of the images that need to be merged. But you will have to figure out the placement of overlapping images due to different size

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @JeruLuke yes sorry for poor choice of words. That is exactly answer or possible solution that I am seeking. I am not sure what techniques would be able to achieve that component in both pictures would be alligned. Or at least I though that would be hardest part and resizing picture would not be that problematic but I might be wrong.

Comment: the mere composition is the most trivial part of all this. you still need at least a resize to scale the image. and then you need to estimate (fiddle with) the parameters like position and scale. if you don't want to tweak numbers going by what the result looks like, you could apply feature matching, but between different modalities (color vs. IR) such features match very poorly.

Answer (score 1):

As as Jeru Luke says

> you will have to figure out the placement of overlapping images due
> to different size

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9.2
#OpenCV 4.5.5, Raspberry pi3B/+, 4b/4g/8g 
#Date: 26th April, 2022

import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('shot.png')
overlay_img1 = np.ones(img1.shape,np.uint8)*255

img2 = cv2.imread('shot1.png')
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape
overlay_img1[450:rows+450, 450:cols+450 ] = img2

img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(overlay_img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray,220,55,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
temp1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img1,img1,mask = mask_inv)
temp2 = cv2.bitwise_and(overlay_img1,overlay_img1, mask = mask)

result = cv2.add(temp1,temp2)
cv2.imshow("Result",result)
cv2.imwrite("Result.jpg",result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output: What you see in shot1 overlay is getting smaller.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I do not understanding your question. Ok. I cannot go any further resolution, because you took picture from smartphone. So no overlay. So here is source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9.2
#OpenCV 4.5.5, Raspberry pi3B/+, 4b/4g/8g 
#Date: 29th April, 2022


import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('RGB_shot.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('IR_shot.png')

# I want to put logo on top-left corner, So I create a ROI
rows,cols,channels = img2.shape

roi = img1[0:rows, 0:cols]

# Now create a mask of logo and create its inverse mask also
img2gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, mask = cv2.threshold(img2gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
mask_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# Now black-out the area of logo in ROI
img1_bg = cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask=mask_inv)

# Take only region of logo from logo image.
img2_fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img2, img2, mask=mask)

# Put logo in ROI and modify the main image
dst = cv2.add(img1_bg, img2_fg)
img1[15:rows+15, 15:cols+15] = dst
cv2.imwrite('photo.png', img1)
cv2.imshow('res', img1)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output for wider IR_shot:
[image]

And here is output result:
[image]

Is that the way you wanted?

Comment: Thanks but problem lies in fact that only this part from IR image HTML <img src="https://i.imgur.com/OdhgYWj.png"> is component (Im on phone currently so wasnt able to mark it better)

Comment: Do u want to cover breadboard instead of overlay?

Comment: I would like to achieve that IR shot would be on top of RGB one(or other way) and you could clearly see which parts were overheating(in IR shot there is one thing emiting heat next to light bulb that is not supposed to) and I would like to clearly see where it was on RGB... I achieved that in Inkscape by doing it by hand and eye but I seeking some solution with code where I put in 2 shots(rgb,ir) and they overlap on right spot so its visible even when I change to different board and dont have to do it by hand again.

Comment: You wanted  IR shot to be on the top of RGB(breadboard)? right?

Comment: I want breadboard from IR shot to be on top of breadboard from RGB shot